# Show that for $0<||A||<\epsilon$ we have $||e^{A}-I||>0$

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces, matrix-exponential

I want to show that there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that if an $n \times n$ matrix $A$ satisfies $0<||A||<\epsilon$, we have $||e^{A}-I||>0$.

This seems pretty simple, but my attempts to derive a strict lower bound haven't gone anywhere.
I have tried expanding out the matrix power series and using the norm triangle inequality but that hasn't been very fruitful. Some help would be much appreciated.

Comment: As written, it's hella trivial. Do you mean $\leq$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that
$$\begin{align*}
||e^A-I|| &= \left|\left|A + \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{A^n}{n!}\right|\right| \\
&\geq ||A|| - \left|\left|\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{A^n}{n!}\right|\right| \\
&\geq ||A|| - \sum_{n=2}^\infty\left|\left|\frac{A^n}{n!}\right|\right| \\
&\geq ||A|| - \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{||A||^n}{n!} \\
&= 1 + 2||A|| - e^{||A||}
\end{align*}$$

Now just show that $1+2x-e^x > 0$ for small $x>0$.